# Split string into array on first non-numeric character in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I want to split a string into an array containing all leading digits as one value and the rest of the string as the second value:

```
3px -> Array('3','px')
01b -> Array('01','b')
01 -> Array('01','')
b -> Array('','b')
1.5 -> Array('1','.5')
300,5 -> Array('300',',5')
a1 -> Array('','a1')
```

In PHP you could do something like:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('/([0-9]+)([^0-9]+)/',$value,$matches);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use `.match` instead of `split`: match and capture digits, then match and capture anything else in a different capture group:

```js
const doSplit = str => {
  const [, ...arr] = str.match(/(\d*)([\s\S]*)/);
  return arr;
};
console.log(
  doSplit('3px'),
  doSplit('01b'),
  doSplit('01'),
  doSplit('b'),
);
```

- `(\d*)` - matches digits
- `([\s\S]*)` - matches absolutely anything after that

Answer (score 0):

just do `str.match(/([0-9]+)([^0-9]+)/).splice(1)` where `str` is the variable containing your value.

Comment: Seems like this does not work with `1.5 -> Array('1','.5')`

Answer (score 0):

You can do somethinglike this:

```
var str = "Hello world!";
var res = [str.substring(0, 1), str.substring(1)];
```

This stores the string in a variable, and then creates an array containing 2 elements. The first will be a substring of the string containing the value from the start to the 1st position, and the second value will be a substring containing the value from the second position, and as no second parameter is supplied, until the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on this one. Hope it helps.
Good luck!

```
function parseString(str) {
  var num = [];
  var nonNum = [];
  for (let i of str.split("")) {
    if (/\D/.test(i)) {
      nonNum.push(i)
      break;
    } else {
      num.push(i)
    }
  }

  if (num.length !== 0) {
    return [num.join(""), str.substring(num.length)]
  } else {
    return (num.length === 0) ? ["", str] : [num.join(""), ""]
  }
}

console.log(parseString("3px"), parseString("01b"), parseString("01"), parseString("b"), parseString("1.5"), parseString("300,5"), parseString("a1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel this question points out a benefit in PHP which we do not enjoy in Javascript. I wrote a little hack for this. I hope it helps.

```
function split_non_numeric(str){
    let strValue = '';
    let intValue = parseInt(str, 10);
    let matchPattern = str.match(new RegExp(intValue));

    if(matchPattern === null){
        intValue = '';
        strValue = str;
    }else{
        if(matchPattern.index > 0){
            intValue = str.substr(0, matchPattern.index + matchPattern[0].length);
            strValue = str.substr(matchPattern.index + matchPattern[0].length);
        }else{
            intValue = str.slice(matchPattern.index, matchPattern[0].length)
            strValue = str.substr(matchPattern[0].length);
        }
    }

    return [intValue, strValue];
}

console.log(split_non_numeric('3px')); // [ '3', 'px' ]
console.log(split_non_numeric('01b')); // [ '01', 'b' ]
console.log(split_non_numeric('01')); // [ '01', '' ]
console.log(split_non_numeric('b')); // [ '', 'b' ]
console.log(split_non_numeric('1.5')); // [ '1', '.5' ]
console.log(split_non_numeric('300,5')); // [ '300', ',5' ]
console.log(split_non_numeric('a1')); // [ '', 'a1' ]
```