# Split string by all non-numeric characters

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this:

```
let s = '10p6s23'
```

I'd like to split it in such a way that I get the numbers and the letters in an array, so ideally I'd get this:

```
 [10,'p',6,'s',23]
```

The ultimate goal is to build a add/subtract calculator where p = + and s = -. So the string above would resolve to `10 + 6 - 23 = -7`.

### *What I've tried*

[Split string into array on first non-numeric character in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59368077/split-string-into-array-on-first-non-numeric-character-in-javascript)

This worked well, except it only split on the first char, not all chars.

Comment: what is the goal? why not replace letters with operator and take `eval`?

Comment: @NinaScholz OK how would you do that?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it: `eval(s.split('p').join('+').split('s').join('-'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const regexp = /(\d+|[a-z]+)/g;
const str = '10p6s23';

const array = [...str.match(regexp)];
console.log(...array);

let replaced = array.map(item => {
  switch(item) {
    case 'p':
      return '+';
    case 's':
      return '-';
    default:
      return item;
  }
}).join('');

console.log(eval(replaced));
```

Comment: Based on @NinaScholz comment, you can also use eval: `eval(s.split('p').join('+').split('s').join('-'))`

Answer (score 1):

you can use match function here.

```
'10p6s23'.match(/[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+/g)

// /[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+/g this is the regular expression for numbers or letters
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by using a Regular Expression

```js
let s = '10p6s23'

const numbers = [...s.matchAll(/\d+/g)].map((num) => parseInt(num));
const operators = [...s.matchAll(/\D+/g)];


console.log(numbers);
console.log(operators);
```

And work from here with the rest of the logic

Answer (score 0):

You could split on:

- digits preceded by a letter i.e. `(?<=[a-z])\d+` or
- letters preceded by a digit i.e. `(?<=\d)[a-z]+`

Afterwards, you will have the filter on non-empty values.

```js
const regexp = /((?<=[a-z])\d+|(?<=\d)[a-z]+)/ig;
const str = '10p6s23';

const array = str.split(regexp).filter(x => x.length);
console.log(...array);
```

Here is an iterative replacement solution:

```js
const compute = (input) => {
  let
    count = input.match(/[ps]/g).length,
    result = input;
  while (count --> 0) {
    result = result.replace(
      /(\d+)([ps])(\d+)/,
      (_, left, op, right) => {
        switch (op) {
          case 'p': return parseInt(left, 10) + parseInt(right, 10);
          case 's': return parseInt(left, 10) - parseInt(right, 10);
        }
      }
    );
  }
  return result;
};

console.log(compute('10p6s23'));
```